# how to install new api of android in visual studio?

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.android, android-sdk-manager

i just have android 6.0(API 23) on my xamarin android project. and its only installed SDK on my windows. now days i want to have a package named `Xamarin.Androis.SupportV7.RecyclerView` in my project but iv got this:

> Could not install package 'Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.RecyclerView 25.3.1'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets 
>   'MonoAndroid,Version=v6.0', but the package does not contain any assembly references or content files that are compatible with that framewo

peoples says i have to targeting android version 7 or higher on my project ....
so i want to install android7 sdk on my system...please tell my how can i add `api24 or 25` on my system???
this is my sdk manager[image]

Answer (score 1):

For installing a new Android API, open your Android SDK Manager and then click in Packages -> Reload. After the reload, it should show the new available versions and APIs

[image]

Now I have API 26 (Android 8), API 25 (Android 7.1.1), API 24 (Android 7.0) and until API 7 (Android 2.1).

I hope this can help you.

Comment: i did it but no thing were load as new api...i updated my Android SDK manager..then it worked out